# Disable Drag & Drop of windows explorer using Delphi

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

How can  i disable Drag & Drop item of Windows Explorer using Delphi APP ?
I want to disable Drag & Drop that user can,t drag any file form Windows Explorer ...

Regards, Mojtaba .

Comment: You mean to disable drag&drop system-wise?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, as this is a question with a very high potential for abuse.  If there is code that can accomplish this, I'd prefere it to not show up here where prospective malware authors can easily find it.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is a way an **application** which runs at the same security level as the user could possibly control something like that throughout the whole system.

It is possible that something like this can be controlled using the OS' Group Policy support. You should search on MS' site for information about Group Policy. However, that is such a fundamental feature of the OS, the better approach may be to control what can be copied where through ACLs on the the files you want to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Just a signal :-) You need to learn about system wide *hooking*. Hook (intercept) the mouse message, then do whatever you want. So go googling it now!

**Update:**

Once upon a time, this can be done easily by modifying certain registry settings, but as far as I concern, the settings now don't work anymore. However, I've ever read a Microsoft article which recommends to set the drag sensitivity through some registry settings.